# Как на десктопе поменять элементы?

Tags: html, css

1 итем слева

2 итем по центру

3 и 4 итемы  прижать в правую сторону

---

сейчас же так

1 итем и 2 итем слева

3 по центру

4 справа

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}

.first {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.second {}

.third {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.fourth {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrap {
    grid-template-columns: min-content min-content 1fr min-content;
  }

  .item {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }

  .third {
    justify-self: center;
  }

}



.wrap div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item first">1</div>
  <div class="item second">2</div>
  <div class="item third">3</div>
  <div class="item fourth">4</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В приложенном коде вы создаёте 3 колонки и помещаете туда 4 элемента. Если вы хотите чтобы 4 элемента находились в 4 разных колонках, то вам, соответственно нужно создавать не 3, а 4 колонки, а для управления их шириной вам нужно подбирать нужные вам параметры.

Пример: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` чтобы создать 4 одинаковые колонки.

P.S. - Как правильно управлять местоположением контента в таблице рассказывается в [этой](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout) статье.